# JavaScript Form Validation TypeError

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, validation, reactjs

I am wanting to prevent my form being submitted or firing GA event on the button click, until both required fields are completed. At the moment when I hit the submit button I am getting an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined
```

I think this is because my two required fields are in an array, but am not sure if that is what the problem is. Any help would be appreciated.

My Form

```
<div id="reveal-form" class="newsletter__form">
    <form action="https://go.pardot.com/l/233333" id="signUpForm">
          <label>Full Name
              <input type="text" name="name" required>
          </label>
          <label>School Email
              <input type="email" name="email" required>
          </label>
          <button class="button" type="submit" value="Submit" id="newsletter-form-button">
              Sign Up
          </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

my JS

```
const requiredFields = this.iframeDocument.getElementById('signUpForm').querySelectorAll('[required]');

    this.formButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (!requiredFields.validity.valid) {
            this.event.preventDefault();
        }
        this.signup();
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah, if `requiredFields` is an array you cant call `.validity.valid` on it

Comment: @Craicerjack `requiredFields` is (only) an array-like collection ([NodeList]([NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList))

Comment: Is there a way to iterate over the two fields to check if they are valid?